# Want to sort photos from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<div class="interface_wrapper">
 <div class="interface">
  <% current_user.friends.each do |f| %>
  <% f.photos.each do |p| %>
  <div class='image_wrapper'>
   <div class='image'>
    <div class="img">
     <%= image_tag(p.url) %>
```

I want to sort |p| on created time.
Attribute in the model(Photo) is created_time.
Can someone help me?

Comment: You need to include more information about what you've tried and what's not working. Error messages too - if available.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<div class="interface_wrapper">
 <div class="interface">
  <% current_user.friends.each do |f| %>
  <% f.photos.order("created_time desc").each do |p| %>
  <div class='image_wrapper'>
   <div class='image'>
    <div class="img">
     <%= image_tag(p.url) %>
```

However, I suppose this is not the correct way. Sorting logic should not be decided in views. Instead have a scope defined in your Photo model and use it to fetch ordered photos.